# Passing data to an array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't get this to work.  I've read the documentation and other sources, but I am just not understanding. I simply want to pass data that I retrieve with ajax to an empty array. I've ensured that the data is indeed successfully coming from the server, but it does not appear to get assigned to UserArticles, and does not update the DOM. What am I missing. Here's my code:

Component:

```
Vue.component('article-selection', {
    props: ['articles'],
    template: '<div> <p>{{articles.title}}</p> </div>'
})
```

Vue:

```
var Article = {};
var UserArticles = [];

var vm = new Vue({
el: '#createNewArticle',
data: {
    Article: Article,
    UserArticles: UserArticles
},
computed: {
    isNewArticle: function () {
        return this.Article.ArticleIdentification.Id.length < 5
    }
},
created: function(){
    this.getUserArticles();
},
methods: {
    setUserId: function (id) {
        //code
    },
    createNewArticle: function (msg) {
        //code},
    getUserArticles: function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/api/Article/GetUserArticles"
        }).done(function (rData, status, jq) {
            UserArticles = rData;
            toastr.success('', 'Retrieved User Articles');

        }).fail(function (rData, status, error) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(rData.responseText);
            toastr.warning(result.messages, 'Retrieve User Articles')
        });
    }
}
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="createNewArticle" >
<div class="col-sm-12">

    <!--Create Initial article-->
    <div class="row" v-if="true">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <div>Passed: {{Article.UserId}}</div>
            <div class="form" style="display: inline-block;" id="newArticleForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ArticleName">Article Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ArticleTitle"
                           name="ArticleTitle" v-model="Article.ArticleIdentification.Title" /><br />

                    <p>{{Article.ArticleIdentification.Title}}</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm" v-on:click="createNewArticle('hey hey')">
                        Create New Article
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <!--COMPONENT HERE--!>
            <article-selection v-for="(artId, index) in UserArticles"
                               v-bind:key="artId.id"
                               v-bind:index="index"
                               v-bind:articles="artId"></article-selection>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: in your $Ajax response user arrow function like this  () => and update your data model like : this.UserArticles = rData

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the method like this

```
 $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/Article/GetUserArticles"
        success: function (data) {
            UserArticles  = data;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use an arrow function in my ajax code inside of the done function as well as add the this keyword. Note the difference:

```
getUserArticles: function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/Article/GetUserArticles"
    }).done((rData, status, jq) => {
        this.UserArticles = rData;
        toastr.success('', 'Retrieved User Articles');

    }).fail(function (rData, status, error) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(rData.responseText);
        toastr.warning(result.messages, 'Retrieve User Articles')
    });
}
```